# Calling base methods on class derived from List<T>

Tags: c#, list, radix

I have a class derived from List:

```
public class B : List<A>
{
}
```

How can I call List methods on B? E.g.

```
var test = new B();
test = test.OrderBy(s=>s.SomeProperty);
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: `OrderBy` is extension method, it belongs to another class (`System.Linq.Enumerable`), not `List<T>`, to use it, add `using System.Linq;` to code.

Comment: Just call them like you have a List. `test.Add(new A())` will call Lists Add method.

Comment: So what is your question about... calling `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods such as `OrderBy()`, or assigning the result to `test`?

Comment: It results an IEnumerable<A> object, not a B, and when I try to cast, I get exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639209/calling-base-methods-on-class-derived-from-listt/30639610#comment49343387_30639341), you want to assign the result of `IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy()` to a `B` variable.

You can't do that, as there is no implicit conversion from `IEnumerable<T>` (or rather `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` to `B`.

Just as you can't do:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string> { "foo", "bar" };
stringList = stringList.OrderBy(s => s);
```

You can't do that with your own type. For the above code the fix is simple:

```
stringList = stringList.OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
```

You can for example implement a constructor, extension method or implicit or explicit conversion to solve this:

```
public class B : List<A>
{
    public B(IEnumerable<A> items)
    {
        base.AddRange(items);
    }
}
```

Then assign a new instance:

```
test = new B(test.OrderBy(s=>s.SomeProperty));
```

Anyway you shouldn't want to inherit from `List<T>`, read [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt).

Comment: Try reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Read your question in the mindset of someone who doesn't know what you're doing. That will really help you reword the question so it's clear from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to assign `test.OrderBy(...)` to `test` then you need to do it like this:

```
IEnumerable<A> test = new B();
test = test.OrderBy(s => s.SomeProperty);
```

But doing that would prevent you adding anything to `test`.

You'd need to do it this way:

```
B b = new B();
/* add items to `b` here */
IEnumerable<A> test = b;
test = test.OrderBy(s => s.SomeProperty);
```

Comment: @CodeCaster - Yes, I interpreted the question as being how to do the `test = test.OrderBy(s => s.SomeProperty);` assignment.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I was reading between the lines in the OP's question. I don't think it's about the enumerable extension methods per se.

Comment: Well of course after 125 questions you'd expect someone to be able to ask a proper question, and not such a vague one.

Comment: It results an IEnumerable<A> object, not a B, and when I try to cast, I get exception

Comment: @Tom - I ran the above code in LINQPad and it worked fine for me. Perhaps double-check and let me know what you're doing that is different.